# Do magento 2 extensions need to care about theme compatibility?

Tags: magento2, theme

Some extensions like Magento 2 layered navigation, reward points, one step checkout, free gift compatible with which theme would be a plus?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help: By default all the extensions are compatible for Luma and Blank theme. Whenever we create new theme their parent theme can one oh these themes but it is not compulsory. We have to check after installing any extension on frontend and have to do changes.

As an example: [Layered navigation](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-layered-navigation/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwqs6lBhCxARIsAG8YcDgHarBYwUUA_jtijiJ1N6Jd6noFLSaSHhMJgkcgYkSHFoVcNnF4F2saAoAzEALw_wcB)

You can use Hyva theme the below extension is compatible with it:
https://mirasvit.com/magento-2-extensions/layered-navigation.html

For more type of extensions you have to do RnD for every extension to there support and also have to do some changes according to it.

Please also refer and search links like this: https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/magento-2-mobile-themes.html

you can also contact theme support so they can guide you more clearly, sometimes many extensions are supported by themes only.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you know some extensions like Magento 2 layered navigation, reward points, one step checkout, free gift compatible with which theme would be a plus? @Ankit

Comment: I edited my answer please look into it again.